# Clickable SVG Images for Website

Tags: python, svg, graphviz, clickable, pydot

I'm using `pydot` to generate SVG graph images. I noticed on this website: http://safemap.sourceforge.net/demo/index-no-refresh.html that they have a clickable SVG. (This website also shows how you can style SVGs with CSS: https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/)

I've been searching for documentation on generating clickable SVGs with `pydot`, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Just add a click event to them - they behave and are regular DOM elements

Comment: OP's asking about library capabilities, not about SVG in general.

Answer (score 4):

You may

- use the [URL attribute](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#a:URL) of nodes and edges
- use [HTML-Like Labels](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#html) for nodes and edges

the latter gives you more freedom of formatting by using tables.

Comment: Thanks you!! The `href` attribute of the HTML-like labels works like a charm. I couldn't get the URL attribute of nodes working. Have you managed?

Comment: I did use HTML like labels for nodes with images, text and links in a family tree.

Answer (score 3):

Pydot is a wrapper for Graphviz. It is reasonable to check if you can do it in Graphviz first.

Turns out you can:

1. To associate URLs with nodes, you can use Graphviz's [URL attribute](http://www.graphviz.org/content/attrs#dURL).
2. To make links clickable in the browser, you can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15841240/2016221).

Now, can you do it with pydot? I believe so, but haven't tested. From taking a look at pydot's source I see it supports any attributes - [in the tests](https://github.com/erocarrera/pydot/blob/1f01e2d71e4cd024815a4934b604299c99540d8e/test/pydot_unittest.py#L316) we see user passes `shape`:

```
self.graph_directed.add_node( pydot.Node('node', shape='box') )
```

and in [the pydot itself](https://github.com/erocarrera/pydot/blob/1f01e2d71e4cd024815a4934b604299c99540d8e/pydot.py#L731) we see that it can support any kind of attributes, not just `shape`:

```
class Node(object, Common):
    (...)
    def __init__(self, name = '', obj_dict = None, **attrs):
        (...)
        self.obj_dict[ 'attributes' ] = dict( attrs )
```

So I'd try using `pydot.Node('node', url='http://somewhere')`. If it fails, I'd construct a `.dot` file manually and pass it through pydot.

#### Warning

If you plan to use SVGs within `<img/>`, chances are your links won't work due to security policy of your web browser. In this case you need to embed it directly into your HTML like the website you linked does. This is especially important if the images are hosted on different domain than the host page.

Comment: Thank you for the help! Unfortunately I couldn't get the `url` attribute of nodes to work (`pydot` throw error when writing the graph). I managed the get the `href` attribute of HTML-like tables working, which is 'good enough' even though I'd rather have the whole node clickable.

Comment: Perhaps it might make a difference if you used uppercase `URL`?

Comment: If I use graphviz and import Digraph then uppercase URL works for me: 
`dot.node('A', 'King Arthur',URL='http://www.google.com/ABC')`